# So long, and thanks for all the herring!

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm resigning as a moderator of Puzzling. I've got a few words and a whole lot of feelings, but I'll try to keep it short.

It's been a long and wonderful journey. I started moderating Puzzling when I was 17, in the midst of high school. I'm 20 now - a year from graduating college. Puzzling has been, to date, the longest-running continuous project I've been involved in. I've grown a deep fondness for the community, and it's been a pleasure watching it grow and succeed. It may not have always been a peaceful journey from beta to graduation, but it certainly has been a rewarding one. I take pride in what we've become, and in all of you, who made this site one of the friendliest and most welcoming I've seen on Stack Exchange to date.

But all things come to pass. My interest in the site has been waning, and with it, my drive to continue moderating here has, too. I feel a little like I've lost the way of things around here, and truthfully, I can't seem to find the motivation to get back into it. While I could continue, I feel it's time for me to pass my diamond on to someone else - someone who is prepared to take a more active role in the site.

Deusovi & GPR are fantastic people to work with, as well. I have to thank them for their work, too, even when I haven't been as present as I really should be. I have high confidence in their care and skill as moderators.

So... it's time for me to step down. And ring the gong of election season on my way out*!

With love.

---

(*Details are forthcoming. You'll hear about the election soon from Stack Community Managers. I'll also continue moderating through the end of the election.)

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work over the years(!). Definitely feel like you've always kept a level head and moderated in the best interest of the site/community. All the best with whatever comes next.

Comment: High school at 17, graduating college by 21? Dang that seems fast... Jokes aside - I look forward to seeing who gets nominated and fills those big shoes of yours. Best of luck out there.

Comment: It's been an honor to moderate alongside you. Good luck over at Literature, and I hope you can spare some time to occasionally drop in! c:

Comment: Aww, really? Won't you at least stay long enough to get a [Sheriff](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/86/sheriff) badge?

Comment: This question should be downvoted into the cellar because we don't want you to leave :-P

Comment: 9000rep flat? Nice.

Comment: Thank you for everything Emrakul. All the very best for your future endeavors :)

Comment: are you still going to be on the site?

Comment: It's *weird* to see your name here without the diamond.

Comment: @randal'thor You're telling _me_!

Answer (score 23):

I haven't known you as well, and as long as others, but you have done a fantastic job!

We will be sad to see you step down, you brought a lot to this site. Your commitment here should be something that's looked up to.

You have done two terms as moderator, and two very successful ones. First being voted to be Moderator Pro Tempore, and then an elected Moderator, the community's faith in you has definitely been rewarding.

I know that you are mod on literature as well, and can understand that a lot of your attention will be there at the moment. I hope you do as well there as you did here.

But if this must come to an end, as all things do, then I thank you for all the hard work you have put into the site!

As a small tribute: [Farewell Emrakul, here's a truly puzzling goodbye](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/51376/18250)

Answer (score 14):

Every era must end, and this announcement marks the end of another one.
Moderating is a rough job, perhaps especially here, but you've done it well.
Respectful, efficient, firm but fair: I've learned a lot from your moderation.
And we won't mention sandboxes or TMBMP ;-) errors made in good faith.
Keeping this site running, you've contributed more than almost anyone.
Ups and downs, we've had a few; but I've always had respect for you.
Lastly, best of luck for your future endeavours, and see you over at Lit!

### [A riddle for Emrakul](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/51374/5373)

Comment: A[nother] riddle for Emrakul

Answer (score 13):

As sad as I am seeing you go, I can fully understand your reasoning. In fact, 3 years of regular, uninterrupted high-participation moderation here on site is more than I would have been able to offer and you have my deepest respect for that.

I hope a lot of people will recognize dedication and good work by up-voting your announcement post here - not for finding your stepping down agreeable, of course, but to up-vote your efforts here.

I also want to leave you with two more points:

- Best wishes for the future! I'm sure, the skills you have developed and displayed here as site moderator will be useful in whatever level ne of work you're going to take up. Just don't forget to mention them on your CV! Also, I'm sure several people here ( including me ) will be willing to testify this and write you a letter of recommendation to that effect, should you need it. Don't hesitate to request one.
- Life is a constant up- and down, and while the next weeks, months or years might keep you or your interest away from this site, don't let that be a hindrance to 'come back' when it again suits you.