# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Puzzling's [second moderator election](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Gareth McCaughan] [image: Rubio]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking Emrakul, who is [stepping down](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/so-long-and-thanks-for-all-the-herrings). Our loss is [Literature's gain](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/80/emrakul?tab=profile).

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5647403835195392/0).

Comment: Thanks again, everyone, for a healthy, effective, and productive election. I've got confidence in Gareth and Rubio, and wish them the best of skill.

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators, and good luck!

Comment: Congratulations Gareth and Rubio, well done!

Comment: Congratulations to the newly elected, and thank you Emrakul for your time here.

Answer (score 11):

Oh great, now *all* our mods are a bunch of noobs who wouldn't know a spaghetti party from a TMBMP.

;-)

**Congrats to Gareth and Rubio!** We've all seen a lot of you around as puzzlers (well, puzzle *solvers* in Gareth's case), and you've already shown your mettle in moderation as room owners of the Sphinx's Lair, the main PSE chatroom. I'm sure you'll have an easy transition into diamondhood and we'll hardly notice any change. Both of you got my votes in the election.

**Thanks also to all the other candidates.** While I think Rubio and Gareth were very clear frontrunners from the moment they nominated themselves, I'm sure any of the others would also have done well in the role of mod. The election wouldn't have been interesting without you. Thank you for volunteering yourselves, and better luck next time.

**Finally, a fond farewell to Emrakul.** I've already written my Emrakulian eulogy [elsewhere](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5912/5373), but once again, your standing down marks another milestone in the site's history. The pro-tem team, who weathered so much during the site's early months, is no more. But at least you'll still be around on Literature, and in TL to share your experience with the new mods.

### GRAURBEITOH!

Comment: As for who got my third vote ... well, maybe I'll make a puzzle out of it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. What's TMBMP?

Comment: @AJ It's a term a few people have adopted to refer to [this post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1601/20), which Made A Lot Of People Very Angry And Was Widely Regarded As A Bad Move. Deconstructing that post and its historical context is... surprisingly complicated, actually. I don't think many people really even remember the timeline of, for example, how we got from spaghetti questions to that post. But the site right now is vastly different than what it was at that time, and I think that post is maybe better left as history.

Comment: @randal'thor Do you really think that I am gonna ask *what's GRAURBEITOH*? :P

Comment: @AJ No, I hope you and other readers are going to work it out and not need to ask :-)

Comment: I'm slightly disappointed that the GRAURBEITOH addition is not the puzzle promised in the first comment.